# Do the Wightman axioms uniquely fix the representation of the Poincaré group on the one-particle states given the representation on the fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, group-representations, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry

Let $P := \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\ltimes \mathbb{R}^4$ be the universal cover of the connected component of the identity of the Poincaré group.

Given a classical field $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{1,3}\to V$ where $V$ carries a finite-dimensional irreducible representation $\rho : P\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$  (e.g. spinor, vector, (p,q)-tensor) and the irreducible *unitary* representation $U : P\to \mathrm{U}(H)$ where $H$ is the space of one-particle states associated to the field, the Wightman axioms impose that
$$ \rho(\Lambda,a)\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x+a) = U(\Lambda,a)\phi(x)U(\Lambda,a)^\dagger$$
holds as an operator equation on the space of states.

Does this equation uniquely determine $U$ given $\rho$? If yes, how? If no, how do we know which one to choose? If this does not work for arbitrary fields, is there at least a recipe for free fields?

---

I'll now describe what thoughts I have so far:

For the massive case I believe the answer is "natural": By Mackey's theory of induced representations, the unitary irreducible representations of $P$ are given by choosing an element of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and a unitary irreducible representation of the stabilizer of $\alpha$ in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ together with a unitary character $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathrm{U}(1)$, which I think is usually just 1 in physics. The stabilizer is known as the "little group" leaving the momentum of a particle in its rest frame invariant. For massive particles, this is $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and since the finite-dimensional representations of $\mathrm{SO}(1,3)$ in which the fields transform are given by representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$, i.e. half-integers $(s_1,s_2)$, we choose the representation $s_1+s_2$ of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ to induce the full representation.

For the massless case, it becomes less natural - the little group is $\mathrm{ISO}(2) = \mathrm{SO}(2)\ltimes\mathbb{R}^2$, which has one-dimensional representation (labeled by the value of "helicity") as well as infinite-dimensional irreducible representations. The latter, I believe, are the "continuous spin representations" usually not occuring in physics. But what determines which one-dimensional representation to choose? The photon usually gets the *reducible* representation that is a sum of the representations of helicity +1 and -1, since parity interchanges them - can this be seen simply from the finite-dimensional representation of the field and knowing it's massless?

For the tachyonic case, I'm completely at a loss. The little group is $\mathrm{SU}(1,1)\cong\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, which has a plethora of rather complicated unitary irreducible representations given by [Bargmann's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SL2(R)#Unitary_representations). I see no way to connect the representation of the field with any of these representations.

Comment: $\partial_t U(I,(t,0,0,0))\bigr\rvert_{t=0}$ is the Hamiltonian of the theory. Therefore I don't see how it can be uniquely determined by the spinor/scalar/... nature of the field and the Wightman axiom. Think of a free scalar theory, and an interacting theory with $\lambda\phi^2$ interaction (in order not to bother about well-defineteness). They both obey the axiom, but the $U$s have to be different.

Comment: @yuggib: I allow the mass as an extra input, so that specific interaction doesn't bother me, but I see your point. I'd be happy if there is a recipe for the free theories, then.

Comment: I don't understand some of your words. By the last $\phi$ you meant the field operator? Then $U(\Lambda,a)$ is not a 1-particle representation, it is the Fock representation (field operators acting on the Fock space). In this way, $\rho (\Lambda,a)$ uniquely determines  $U(\Lambda,a)$ by dictating how it acts on the 1-particle states.

Comment: @ophelia: Yes, $\phi$ is the field - and yes, the Wightman axiom is a priori for the full reducible representation on the full space of states, but it clearly must descend to the irreducible representations sitting inside that full representation, i.e. $UAU^\dagger$ cannot carry an operator $A$ restricted to an irreducible representation to an operator that acts non-trivially outside that representation.

Comment: For free theories this should hold true. I am not an expert, you should see the so-caled Shale-Stinespring theorem ([this paper for free boson fields](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1962-103-01/S0002-9947-1962-0137504-6/)). It surely addresses existence; maybe also uniqueness.

Comment: See also [this one](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/36/4/36_4_511/_article). I am not sure they address uniqueness however...

Comment: The field operator has non trivial domain, so I would not write it that way. .. Anyway, yuggib addressed the uniqueness of the connection between $\rho$ and $U$ , but I think maybe you are wondering how to establish the connection (that is, connecting the Wigner rotation  and embedded representation), then maybe you want to look at [http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/prop.19740220302/abstract ]  (sorry, I don't know how to add a link). From my point of view, the natural way is to go from $U$ to $\rho$, and not the other way around.

Comment: I guess no, since the one-particle states might be bound states of other particles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does if adding the invariance requirement of the vacuum state stated in the Wightman axioms. That is a general result valid as a consequence of the *GNS construction*.

Let us start from the fact that the algebra of observables ${\cal A}$ is the (unital) $^*$-algebra of finite linear combinations of finite products of smeared field operators $\phi(f)$.

The action of Poincaré group induces a $^*$-algebra representation $SO(1,3)_+\times \mathbb{R}^4 \ni g \mapsto \alpha_g : {\cal A} \to {\cal A}$ completely defined by requiring that
$$\alpha_g(\phi(f)) := \rho_g \phi(g(f))$$
and extending it to the whole algebra by imposing that it is linear, preserves the adjoint and the products (and the unit),
where $g(f)$ is the standard action of the group on test functions.

Let us indicate the vacuum state by $\Omega$. The above representation has the property that, *according to Wighhman axioms*,  *it leaves invariant the $n$-point functions of the vacuum state*
$$\langle \Omega, \phi(f_1) \cdots \phi(f_n) \Omega \rangle =
\langle \Omega, \alpha_g(\phi(f_1)) \cdots \alpha_g(\phi(f_n)) \Omega \rangle\:, $$ which extends to
$$\langle \Omega, A\Omega \rangle =
\langle \Omega, \alpha_g(A) \Omega \rangle \tag{1}$$
for a generic element $A\in {\cal A}$ and every $g \in SO(1,3)_+\times \mathbb{R}^4$.

Using the fact that $\phi({\cal A}) \Omega$ is *dense* in the Hilbert space  (again as a consequence of Wightman  axioms)
and (1), it is not difficult to prove that

*there is only one unitary representation of $SO(1,3)_+\times \mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying, for every $g\in SO(1,3)_+\times \mathbb{R}^4$ and every test function $f$*,
$$U_g A U_g^{-1} := \alpha_g(A)\:, \quad U_g \Omega = \Omega$$
where  $A \in {\cal A}$, in particular
$$U_g \phi(f) U^{-1}_g = \alpha_g(\phi(f))\:.$$
The representation $U$ is *completely defined* by requiring
$$U_g A \Omega := \alpha_g(A)\Omega$$
for every $g\in SO(1,3)_+\times \mathbb{R}^4$ and $A\in {\cal A}$.

If the state $\Omega$ is *Gaussian*, i.e., *its Wightman functions are determined by the two-point function using the Wick rule (and the $1$-function vanishes)*, then the Hilbert space is a *Fock one* and it is not difficult to prove that the above representation leaves invariant the one-particle space (and in general the $n$-particle space).

In this case, a well defined unitary representation arises in the one-particle space just by restricting $U$ to it.

*However, the above result is valid also if $\Omega$ is not Gaussian.*

The result is completely general, we only need a $^*$-representation of a group on the $*$-algebra of observables generated by the smeared field operators and a state determined by its Wightman functions which are invariant under the action of the group. This automatically determines a unique unitary representation of the group leaving the vector state invariant and which implements the action of the group.